Polars read_parquet method converts the original date value to a different value if the date is invalid
I'm reading a parquet file from S3 bucket using polars and below is the code that i use:
df = pl.read_parquet(parquet_file_name, storage_options=storage_options, hive_partitioning=False)

In the S3 bucket, the value (which is invalid as the year is 0200) of the date column is stored as
 start_date = 0200-03-01 00:00:00

After reading this value from S3 bucket using polars.read_parquet method, it internally converts the date as
 start_date = 1953-10-28 10:43:41.128654848

and it sets the datatype in the polars dataframe as Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone=None) for that column.
Is there any way that i can retain the date as is even if it is invalid? I tried doing cast but it doesn't help because the read_parquet method internally reads it as 1953-10-28 and doing any cast on top of already converted value doesn't help.
Any help would be highly appreciated please.
Note: Also, for comparison purpose, i tried using pandas and it behaves same like polars i.e., the start_date is 1953-10-28 10:43:41.128654848

How was the data originally saved as parquet-file? The issue probably needs to be solved there (e.g. save the date as string column and have a separate column indicating, which row is valid or just a placeholder).

Hi @Hericks, the data in S3 is originally saved as date format I e., 0200-03-01. Out of million records, just this record is invalid but rest is all valid. As part of the transformation, we just need to read the data as is from S3. Also we don't have an option to change the schema to add new column.

I was more asking about how this data was written to the parquet-file in the first place (i.e. how an invalid date made it into a date column). I could be mistaken, but think that this should fail on write already.

Hi @Hericks, the data from the HDFS is copied to S3 using AWS Datasync task. The data in HDFS and the originating source (Oracle in this case) contains invalid date.

Hi @Hericks there is no data loss happening here as the originating source (Oracle) itself has got the date as '0200-03-01'

For the record, "0200" is not an invalid year at all. I can not reproduce your issue:
>>> df = pl.Series("d", ["0200-03-01 00:00:00"]).str.to_datetime().to_frame()
>>> df
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ d                   │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 0200-03-01 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
>>> df.write_parquet("/tmp/df.parquet")
>>> pl.read_parquet("/tmp/df.parquet")
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ d                   │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 0200-03-01 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘

It is likely the data is corrupted in the parquet itself.

On further investigation it seems that the data pipeline that wrote the parquet was using nanoseconds rather than microseconds as the unit, in which case the year 0200 does underflow. You should fix this source pipeline to use microseconds. The data in the parquet is already corrupted and can no longer be (unambiguously) fixed.

How did you infer that the data used ns instead of ms as unit? Could it be a feasible approach to try df.with_columns(pl.col("start_date").dt.cast_time_unit("ms"))?

Hi @orlp, as part of the data pipeline, the AWS Glue job reads the S3 parquet file, transforms it and writes it to AWS RDS (postgres) as the same value i.e., '0200-03-01'. I'm trying to validate that the RDS data is valid using Polars by reading the S3 bucket parquet file and that is where the problem happens. Polars internally defaults it to nanoseconds rather than microseconds.

@Hericks The OP specified it is so: Datetime(time_unit='ns', time_zone=None).

@BalajiVenkatachalam Polars doesn't default to nanoseconds instead of microseconds, it reads whatever format is in the parquet file. You can easily confirm this by editing my above example with df = pl.Series("d", ["2000-03-01 00:00:00"]).str.to_datetime(time_unit='ns').to_frame(). The file is written and read back in nanoseconds. Whatever is writing your S3 bucket parquet file uses the nanosecond type.

Since this is the only record that is corrupt, the fastest way would be to load the data as you have done with:
 df = pl.read_parquet(parquet_file_name, storage_options=storage_options, hive_partitioning=False)

Then after loading the parquet file into the dataframe either change the value of that date to the date you know is correct (eg. 2000-03-01 00:00:00), or change it to the initial value in the parquet file (0200-03-01 00:00:00)
On a side note, I would recommend scan_parquet, as it is more efficient because it makes use of LazyFrame implementation.
